# How can I remove duplicates when comparing two multi demential arrays?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays. Each has nested arrays within it. I want to create a function that compares the arrays then moves duplicate values into a third array. Keyword here: "move."
I want to remove any duplicates from the first two arrays.

Any suggestions how to do it?

Here are the two arrays I'm comparing:

```
$old_values = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'joe'
        'body' => array(
            'arm' => 'red',
            'leg' => 'blue'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'bob'
        'body' => array(
            'arm' => 'red',
            'leg' => 'blue'
        )
    )
);

$new_values = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'christopher'
        'body' => array(
            'arm' => 'purple',
            'leg' => 'orange'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'bob'
        'body' => array(
            'arm' => 'red',
            'leg' => 'blue'
        )
    )
);
```

Ideally, the output would be this:

```
$duplicate_values = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'bob'
        'body' => array(
            'arm' => 'red',
            'leg' => 'blue'
        )
    )
);
$old_values = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'joe'
        'body' => array(
            'arm' => 'red',
            'leg' => 'blue'
        )
    )
);

$new_values = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'christopher'
        'body' => array(
            'arm' => 'purple',
            'leg' => 'orange'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For finding duplicates and differences use `array_udiff` and `array_uintersect` with custom compare callback function provided

```php
<?php

$compare = fn ($a, $b) => 
    $a['name'] === $b['name']
        ? $a['body']['arm'] === $b['body']['arm']
            ? $a['body']['leg'] <=> $b['body']['leg']
            : $a['body']['arm'] <=> $b['body']['arm']
        : $a['name'] <=> $b['name'];

$old = array_udiff($old_values, $new_values, $compare);
$dup = array_uintersect($old_values, $new_values, $compare);
$new = array_udiff($new_values, $old_values, $compare);

var_dump(
    print_r($old, true),
    print_r($dup, true),
    print_r($new, true),
);
```

Comment: How can the arrays be compared without an anonymous arrow function?